# Duality and Optimality Conditions

Tags: matrices, linear-programming

[image]

I have seen the solution and it involves adding a $x_5$ and $x_6$ to the inequalities. I really do not understand why this happens? I have not seen any questions like this yet.

Any pointers would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My understand is that the standard form only contains equality such as

$min:\  F(X), \\s.t. AX=b, X>0$

so what you should do is to add $x_5\geq0$ and $x_6\geq0$, then the inequality can be written as equality such as
$x_1+x_2-3x_3+x_4+x_5=5$ and
$x_1-x_3+x_6=2$

right now, you only have equalities. Then you can put it into the standard form.

Comment: why not slack variables tho?